# How to troubleshoot webpack "Mod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ccxt

I m using React and just added this module, ccxt. Before adding the module everything is fine. The module installed fine. Later, I added this line to a script:

`const ccxt = require ('ccxt');`

And when I then issue `npm start` it throws an error:

```
[WARN] No ENV file found
[OKAY] Wrapping display Output to 78 Columns
16:29:02 backend.1  |  info: Starting app...
16:29:03 frontend.1 |  events.js:167
16:29:03 frontend.1 |        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
16:29:03 frontend.1 |        ^
16:29:03 frontend.1 |  Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8080
16:29:03 frontend.1 |      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1330:14)
16:29:03 frontend.1 |      at listenInCluster (net.js:1378:12)
16:29:03 frontend.1 |      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1491:7)
16:29:03 frontend.1 |      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:55:10)
16:29:03 frontend.1 |  Emitted 'error' event at:
16:29:03 frontend.1 |      at emitErrorNT (net.js:1357:8)
16:29:03 frontend.1 |      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
internal/util.js:232
  throw new ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL(signal);
  ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL]: Unknown signal: null
    at convertToValidSignal (internal/util.js:232:9)
    at ChildProcess.kill (internal/child_process.js:411:5)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/marcus/development/nodestuff/crypto-crawler/node_modules/foreman/lib/proc.js:49:11)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/marcus/development/nodestuff/crypto-crawler/node_modules/foreman/lib/proc.js:45:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:235:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sails-react-webpack@0.2.0 start: `nf start --wrap`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sails-react-webpack@0.2.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/marcus/.npm/_logs/2018-06-03T21_29_03_091Z-debug.log
```

I tried to "npm install" and get an error (even though npm install --save ccxt runs fine):

```
clean-webpack-plugin: /home/marcus/development/nodestuff/crypto-crawler/public/dist has been removed.
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: /home/marcus/development/nodestuff/crypto-crawler/node_modules/ccxt/js/allcoin.js Unexpected token (60:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Any suggestion what this is telling me or how you might go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8080` seems to indicate that you're trying to run two processes on port 8080.

There isn't enough information here regarding your development evironment / app architecture to tell you specifically what to do, but it sounds like you need to configure either your app server or the cctx to use a different port. My guess is that port 8080 is used by default in cctx.

Try doing a search for `8080` in your app's codebase and change it to something else. Either that or look for configuration options in the cctx documentation to specify a port for it to run on.

Additionally, run `lsof -i | grep 8080` to see if there's any other process on your machine that's using port 8080.

Hope this helped, good luck!